# Applying a function with two arguments using Lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have created a test function, called testFunc which expects two arguments.

```
testFunc<-function(x,y){
  length(x)
  nrow(y)
}
```

Now I want to use lappy to apply this function to a list, keeping the y argument fixed.

Consider a test list, testList:

```
testList<-list(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,5,6),b=c(1,2,4,5,6,7,8))
```

Can we use lapply to run testFunc on testList$a and testList$b with same value of y?

I tried this call:

```
lapply(X = testList, FUN = testFunc, someDataFrame)
```

But I am always getting the length of someDataFrame as the output. Am I missing something obvious.

Comment: Why don't you set your `y` to be fixed within the function and use only `x` as argument? i.e. `testfunc <- function(x, y=...) {...}` ?

Comment: @Sotos : The code as it is posted already does the job. But, I think Tushar wants to return length(x) and nrow(y) both

Comment: Yeah, I thought it didn't make much sense...

Comment: @vasanthcullen I am expecting it to print the values 7, nrow(someDataFrame) two times, since testList has two vectors. All it gives me is 7 and nrow(someDataFrame) once.

Comment: @vasanthcullen Yeah, got it. I should have used print, to print the number of rows. I think the point you made regarding R printing the last evaluated value was the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to

```
testFunc<-function(x,y){
  return(c(length(x), nrow(y)))
}
```

By default, a R function returns the last evaluated value

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way, use a named variable:

`lapply(X = testList, FUN=testFunc, y=someDataFrame)`