# R lapply function with two arguments that are not fixed

Tags: r, lapply

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186263/applying-a-function-with-two-arguments-using-lapply) asked before. My question is a bit more complex than the previous one. For my question, the y parameter is not fixed.

In the function(X,Y){SOME FUNCTION}, X is a list of characters and Y is a list of dataframe. Basically, I want the function to work on the pair of X and Y in sequence respectively, and produce the output as one list. For example, the first element of X list and the first element of Y list, the second element of X list and the second element of Y list, the third element of X list and the third element of Y list,...

Example of X, Y

```
X <- c("1", "2")
y1 <- data.frame("person.1" = "Amy", "bestfood..1" = "fish", "bestthing..1" = "book",
                 "person.2" = "Mike", "bestfood..2" = "fish", "bestthing..2" = "book")
y2 <- data.frame("person.1" = "Amy","bestfood..1" = "carrot", "bestthing..1" = "cloth",
                 "person.2" = "Mike","bestfood..2" = "carrot", "bestthing..2" = "cloth")
Y <- list(y1,y2)
```

The function:

```
  addID <- function(X, Y) {
     rowlength <- length(Y)
     df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = rowlength, ncol = 3))
     colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Person", "Food")
     df[1:nrow(df), 1] <- X

  # name
  namecols <-grep("person",colnames(Y))
  for (i in 1:length(namecols)) {
    name <- Y[1, namecols[i]]
    df[i, 2] <- as.character(name)
  }
  # food
  foodcols <-
  grep("bestfood",colnames(Y))
  for (i in 1:length(foodcols)) {
    food <- Y[1, foodcols[i]]
    df[i, 3] <- as.character(foodcols)
  }

  return(df)
   }
  }
```

I tried to use lapply but can't figure out the way to include the X list. When I try this:

```
lapply(Y, function, X=X)
```

The function doesn't work properly. I wonder if there are other ways to include X in it(I tried the function on individual character and dataframe, it works just fine. )

I hope this is clear. If not, please point it out, I will try my best to clarify. Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE:

I tried Map as suggested by comments. It returns: incorrect number of dimensions. I added some details in the function. It seems like R stucks on the last line.

```
outcome <- Map(addID, Y, X)
```

I get

```
error in Y[1, namecols[i]] : incorrect number of dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1:nrow(df), 1, value = list(person.1 = 1L,  :
 provided 6 variables to replace 1 variables
```

The outcome should looks like:

```
z1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2), Person = c("Amy","Mike"), Food = c("fish", "fish"))
z2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2), Person = c("Amy","Mike"), Food = c("carrot", "carrot"))
outcome <- list(z1,z2)
```

Comment: look into mapply/ Map

Comment: What is  `return(network_df)` in your `test.function`

Comment: `mapply()` iterates over 2 or more vectors/lists in parallel.

Comment: Can you please fix your `addID` function.  There is a `network_df` which is not created inside.  Also, `namecols`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do this easily in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(Y, .id = 'ID') %>% 
    select(ID, starts_with('person'),  contains('food')) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = c(".value"),
       names_pattern = "([^.]+)\\.+\\d+")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  ID    person bestfood
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>   
1 1     Amy    fish    
2 1     Mike   fish    
3 2     Amy    carrot  
4 2     Mike   carrot
```

---

With the OP's function, if we modify, it would work

```
addID <- function(X, Y) {
     rowlength <- length(Y)
     df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = rowlength, ncol = 3))
     colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Person", "Food")
     df[1:nrow(df), 1] <- X
     namecols  <- grep("person",colnames(Y))
     df[, 2] <- unlist(Y[namecols])
     foodcols <- grep("bestfood", colnames(Y))
     df[,3] <- unlist(Y[foodcols])
     

  

  return(unique(df))
   }
```

-testing

```
Map(addID, X, Y)
$`1`
  ID Person Food
1  1    Amy fish
2  1   Mike fish

$`2`
  ID Person   Food
1  2    Amy carrot
2  2   Mike carrot
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, Akrun! unfortunately, Map doesn't work either. I've added some details of the function.

Comment: @zeng156 your function is still not reproducibe for testing purpose

Comment: @zeng156 you showed only part of your function.  So, it is not clear to others what exactly the whole function returns or even your input X, Y.  Are those data.frame or vectors

Comment: @aksun Sorry for the confusion. I only added part of the function because the whole function is very long. The shown part of the function is where it starts to go haywire. I am trying to create a simplified version to see if it gets the same error.

Comment: @zeng156 Based on your error, the inputs are the problem i.e. `Y` and X should have the same length.  If Y is a data.frame, it will loop over the columns, and Xshould have the same length

Comment: Thank you! I will look into that. I've also added a simplified version of the data and function. I hope it could help clarify things.

Comment: @zeng156 what is `addID`?  is it same as the other function

Comment: @aksun sorry, it was a typo. It is corrected now

Comment: @zeng156 I updated with a tidyverse option as your function is having some issues

Comment: @zeng156 please check my update.  I changed your `addID` and tested

Comment: @aksun Thanks for the solution. It worked on the simplified version in the post. I tried to change my original script in the same format, it still gives me the same replacement error. Anyways, I've accepted your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @zeng156 there must be some `list` elements that doesn't have the column pattern you `grep`ped and that may have results in error